# VSTest Exception - VSTS CI Build

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm trying to add code coverage to vstest task. My `dll` project to be tested is `netstandard2.0` and the test project is `netcoreapp2.0`

My build definition is setted as:

1. GitVersion
2. dotnet restore
3. dotnet build
4. VSTest
5. delete files
6. dotnet pack
7. NuGet Push
8. Publish Artifact

At the moment of running VSTest Task, it throws an exception like:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)
```

So, the only thing that I changed on my CI definition since the original was the **EnableCodeCoverage** (setted to true).

Is the anything else to be configured that I have missed?